# importing ip ranges list as a text file in angry ip scanner

Tags: networking, ip, scanner

i don't know how to correctly import ip ranges in a text file for angry ip scanner.i did copy the ip ranges from some website and import them in a .txt file like

`45.5.0.0-45.5.3.255
45.5.15.0-45.5.15.255
45.5.20.0-45.5.23.255
45.5.24.0-45.5.27.255`

but the angry ip scanner just scanned the first ips and not the ranges
so i have no idea how to import ip ranges correctly in a text file to use in angry ip scanner.
i also did something like 192.168.1.1/24 but it ain't worked either.

Comment: Try to export such ranges list from this scanner and reproduce the format of exported file.

Comment: tnx buddy but i didn't get what u mean,i wanna import the ranges not export them,please be a little more specific
@Akina

Comment: 1) It is impossible when a tool can import a list but cannot export it back. And when it exports, the list format is directly the same which it may import without problems. This is the simplest way to obtain an example file which have correct format. 2) I have looking at your tool - it cannot work with ranges list, single range only.

Comment: this is what exactly angry ip scanner documentation wrote but it ain't work 
`IP List File – extracts IP addresses from any text file provided by the user. The file may be in any format – the feeder looks for all tokens similar to IP addresses in it, so output of any exporter can be used later as an input for a new scan. Advanced – provides the ability to specify more complex ruler for generation in textual form (for advanced users), e.g. 192.168-170.150.1-255 or 192.168.0.0/24.`

Comment: and specially i don't get what this format means 192.168-170.150.1-255

Comment: *what this format means 192.168-170.150.1-255* I think this means 192.168.150.1-255 + 192.169.150.1-255 + 192.170.150.1-255.

Answer (score 0):

What I've found out (so far) is:
Angry IP Scanner does not import ranges in any kind (192.168.0.0/24 or 192.168.0.0-255 or ...) but it works if you put on every new line in a text file one IP address from that range so:

```
192.168.0.1
192.168.0.2
     ︙
```

any other text in the line doesn't matter, so if you create an output by using the IP-range option, you can copy the column with the IP addresses to the text file and re-use them in future analysis runs.

So it works, but explanation is hard to find on the Internet, and hopefully Angry IP will get an option to interpret ranges like a.b.c.d/nn.